# How to get property value from response as JSON in Apache Synapse?

Tags: json, mediator, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

Is there a way to get value from response as JSON in Apache Synapse?

Here's an example api mediator.

```
<api context="/accounts">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://localhost:8988/accounts/">
                    </address>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log>
                <property name="Status" expression="get-property('status')">
            </log>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Call from `http://localhost:8988/accounts/` will result in this json:

```
{
   "accountNumber": "1234567890123456",
   "status": "active"
}
```

Upon hit on `outSeqeunce>log` there's no result being get from `get-property('status')`.

I know that there's a function in WSO2 like `json-eval` but solution must be limited on using Apache Synapse.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I really understand your question or  why you don't want to use JSON path expression.

Maybe this is a solution. You can transform the JSON to XML by simply setting a property.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

You should then be able to access it using XPath expressions. The following link will explain how to do this.

[JSON Support](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/JSON+Support)